# If WinExist using variable and RegEx

Tags: autohotkey

Disclaimer: Yes I have read another StackOverflow posts similar to mine, but none were using RegEx on the title, and I couldnt find a solution.

I need to open a certain window that is like this:

`PlayerName - Game Version 1.2.15`

where PlayerName can be everything (like aywradwe, john or flyingcar82)

I can get the player name from a certain function `getName()` that is irrelevant for my question and its working properly.

`playerName = getName()`

And then I tried to open the correct window by using that `playerName` variable and RegEx to match any possible version of the game.

```
 SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
 playerName = getName()
 IfWinExist, playerName - Game Version.*
 {
 WinActivate  
 Sleep, 500
 WinMaximize
 }
```

But it tries to match the title using "playerName" and not its value. I also tried with `%playerName%` and it doesnt work either...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here, and they come from using the legacy syntax wrong.

Problem 1:
`playerName = getName()`
You're using the deprecated legacy way of assigning literal text to a variable ([`=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetEnv.htm)).
Now the variable `playerName` holds the literal text `"getName()"`.
[`:=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm) should be used to assign the result of an expression to a variable:
`playerName := getName()`

Problem 2:
Usage of the deprecated legacy [`IfWinActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm#command) command.
Not exactly a problem on it's own, but combined with wrong usage of the legacy syntax it is. In a legacy statement there you'd indeed refer to the variable by doing `%playerName%`, and that would work if you fixed *Problem 1*.
But lets do it the proper way and use the newer [`WinExist()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm#function) function:

```
if (WinExist(playerName " - Game Version.*")) ;concatenate the contents of a variable and string
{
    WinActivate  
    Sleep, 500
    WinMaximize
}
```

Overall, I'd recommend trying to get rid of the legacy syntax.
Here's a good page on the documentation to get you started between the differences:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm